# How to fix names on map and Warning message in r(ggmap,ggplot)

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, ggrepel

I have created world map that display's country's names on world map. However,My issue is that all the names are overlapping with each other making it hard to see on the map and another issue is that R is displaying warning message saying "missing values".Below is the dataset and other info.

**dput**

```
> dput(d1)
structure(list(area = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 89L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 
125L, 126L, 127L, 129L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 
138L, 140L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 153L, 
155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 161L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", 
"Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", 
"Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", 
"China, mainland", "China, Taiwan Province of", "Colombia", "Congo", 
"Costa Rica", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia", 
"Democratic People's Republic of Korea", "Denmark", "Djibouti", 
"Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", 
"Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", 
"Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", 
"Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", 
"Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", 
"Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", 
"New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", 
"Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", 
"Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", 
"Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Sierra Leone", "Slovakia", 
"Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Tajikistan", 
"Thailand", "The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "Timor-Leste", 
"Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
"United Republic of Tanzania", "United States of America", "Uruguay", 
"Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
    latitude = c(33.94, 41.15, 28.03, -11.2, 17.06, -38.42, -25.27, 
    47.52, 25.03, 23.68, 13.19, 17.19, 9.31, 32.32, -16.29, -22.33, 
    -14.24, 4.54, 42.73, 12.24, 16, 12.57, 7.37, 56.13, 6.61, 
    15.45, -35.68, 22.4, 22.2, 35.86, 23.7, 4.57, -0.23, 9.75, 
    7.54, 21.52, 35.13, 40.34, 56.26, 11.83, 15.41, 18.74, -1.83, 
    26.82, 13.79, -16.58, 61.92, 46.23, -17.68, -0.8, 13.44, 
    51.17, 7.95, 39.07, 12.26, 15.78, 9.95, 11.8, 4.86, 18.97, 
    15.2, 47.16, 64.96, 20.59, -0.79, 32.43, 33.22, 53.41, 31.05, 
    41.87, 18.11, 36.2, 30.59, -0.02, -3.37, 29.31, 19.86, 33.85, 
    -29.61, 6.43, -18.77, -13.25, 4.21, 3.2, 17.57, 35.94, 21.01, 
    -20.35, 23.63, 46.86, 31.79, -18.67, 21.91, -22.96, 28.39, 
    52.13, -20.9, -40.9, 12.87, 17.61, 9.08, 60.47, 30.38, 8.54, 
    -23.44, -9.19, 12.88, 51.92, 39.4, 35.91, 45.94, -1.94, 17.36, 
    13.91, 12.98, -13.76, 0.19, 23.89, 14.5, 8.46, -9.65, -30.56, 
    40.46, 7.87, 3.92, -26.52, 60.13, 46.82, 15.87, -8.87, 8.62, 
    10.69, 33.89, 38.96, 1.37, 23.42, 55.38, -6.37, 37.09, -32.52, 
    -15.38, 6.42, 14.06, 15.55, -13.13, -19.02), longitude = c(67.71, 
    20.17, 1.66, 17.87, -61.8, -63.62, 133.78, 14.55, -77.4, 
    90.36, -59.54, -88.5, 2.32, -64.76, -63.59, 24.68, -51.93, 
    114.73, 25.49, -1.56, -24.01, 104.99, 12.35, -106.35, 20.94, 
    18.73, -71.54, 114.11, 113.54, 104.2, 120.96, -74.3, 15.83, 
    -83.75, -5.55, -77.78, 33.43, 127.51, 9.5, 42.59, -61.37, 
    -70.16, -78.18, 30.8, -88.9, 179.41, 25.75, 2.21, -149.41, 
    11.61, -15.31, 10.45, -1.02, 21.82, -61.6, -90.23, -9.7, 
    -15.18, -58.93, -72.29, -86.24, 19.5, -19.02, 78.96, 113.92, 
    53.69, 43.68, -8.24, 34.85, 12.57, -77.3, 138.25, 36.24, 
    37.91, -168.73, 47.48, 102.5, 35.86, 28.23, -9.43, 46.87, 
    34.3, 101.98, 73.22, -4, 14.38, -10.94, 57.55, -102.55, 103.85, 
    -7.09, 35.53, 95.96, 18.49, 84.12, 5.29, 165.62, 174.89, 
    -85.21, 8.08, 8.68, 8.47, 69.35, -80.78, -58.44, -75.02, 
    121.77, 19.15, -8.22, 127.77, 24.97, 29.87, -62.78, -60.98, 
    -61.29, -172.1, 6.61, 45.08, -14.45, -11.78, 160.16, 22.94, 
    -3.75, 80.77, -56.03, 31.47, 18.64, 8.23, 100.99, 125.73, 
    0.82, -61.22, 9.54, 35.24, 32.29, 53.85, -3.44, 34.89, -95.71, 
    -55.77, 166.96, -66.59, 108.28, 48.52, 27.85, 29.15)), .Names = c("area", 
"latitude", "longitude"), row.names = c(1L, 84L, 207L, 331L, 
440L, 557L, 813L, 941L, 1204L, 1320L, 1443L, 1831L, 1943L, 2060L, 
2163L, 2409L, 2534L, 2671L, 2791L, 2925L, 3040L, 3146L, 3262L, 
3387L, 3527L, 3636L, 3739L, 3867L, 4000L, 4121L, 4267L, 4408L, 
4540L, 4660L, 4789L, 5037L, 5174L, 5438L, 5535L, 5674L, 5781L, 
5892L, 6004L, 6138L, 6272L, 6653L, 6778L, 6911L, 7051L, 7172L, 
7292L, 7533L, 7680L, 7800L, 7943L, 8063L, 8193L, 8305L, 8396L, 
8515L, 8635L, 8767L, 8909L, 9034L, 9168L, 9294L, 9414L, 9534L, 
9670L, 9805L, 9953L, 10072L, 10215L, 10483L, 10610L, 10704L, 
10950L, 11188L, 11317L, 11392L, 11758L, 11883L, 12003L, 12137L, 
12241L, 12357L, 12487L, 12603L, 12722L, 12855L, 13087L, 13216L, 
13330L, 13442L, 13563L, 13684L, 13825L, 13954L, 14088L, 14217L, 
14335L, 14466L, 14730L, 14863L, 14993L, 15115L, 15247L, 15389L, 
15525L, 15659L, 15923L, 16199L, 16307L, 16406L, 16521L, 16630L, 
16738L, 16829L, 16959L, 17206L, 17579L, 17679L, 17819L, 17969L, 
18200L, 18316L, 18433L, 18575L, 18818L, 19079L, 19165L, 19280L, 
19397L, 19523L, 19741L, 20002L, 20123L, 20266L, 20395L, 20536L, 
20783L, 20879L, 21009L, 21118L, 21237L, 21357L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Rcode:**

```
sbbox <- make_bbox(lon = d1$longitude, lat=d1$latitude, f=.1)
s_map <- get_map(location = sbbox,maptype = 'terrain', source = 'google')

ggmap(s_map) +
  geom_point(data=d1, mapping = aes(x=longitude,y=latitude)) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude,label=area), 
                   data=d1,box.padding = 2, point.padding = 0.0005, fontface = 'bold') +
  ggtitle('latitude vs longitude') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.05)) +
  xlab('Hote Longitude') +
  ylab('Hotel Latitude') +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,hjust=0)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

**Warning Message:**

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 15 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 15 rows containing missing values (geom_label_repel). 

Map output:
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: do update the dput and prefix `d1` to it. Because, if the `ggmap` code is executed, it throws error `d1` not found.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please see updated dput

Comment: The warnings arise because not all points in your `d1` dataset could be plotted: some points have latitude / longitude values outside the limits of the map. (According to ggmap's documentation, maps of the whole world are currently not supported.) As for overlapping labels, try making the font size smaller & the output image larger? Though there are so many labels, the result is likely to be unreadable unless you are printing to a full wall...